# Why is php not storing data in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to take some links and store them in a MySQL table. Its not storing the data but I am getting an error message(the one that says "idk man, it didnt get in there"). I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's what I have so far:

```
     // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) 
        {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
       else
       {
        echo "<font  color='#00FF00'>CONNECTED TO DATABASE SUCCESSFULLY</font><br>";
        }

    //find open link record and insert

    foreach ($result as $wtf)
    {
    //now show me
  mysqli_query ($conn,"INSERT INTO carads (adlink) VALUES ('$wtf')");
    echo "<font color='#FFFFFF'>INSERTING LINK INTO DATABASE: $wtf</font><br>";
    }
    $sql="SELECT 'adlink' FROM 'carads'";
    $sqlresult = mysqli_query($conn,$sql );
    //if its messed up tell me now
    if
 ( !$sqlresult)
    {

    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    die("<font size='20' color='#FF0000'>idk man, there was an error and the dataset didnt get in there</font><br>") ;
    }









if ($sqlresult = mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($sqlresult);
  print_r ("<font size='18' color='#00FF00'>Car ads Database has %d ADLINKS from current city.\n</font><br>",$rowcount);






  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
//close the connection
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Once again, Im all turned around here and needing a little help from smart people. Why is it not storing the links in the database?

Comment: And does it give an error message before the one you cite?  The one you send isn't helpful to programmers, but the one before is.

Comment: result is the array of links that goes in there...its before this, just before I declare values for the connection variables. Iknow thats working fine because it outputs the long list of links and says "Inserting into db: link"...I thought I had some malformed sql but do you think it could be that? @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: `mysqli_error($conn);` give this `error` not the one you giving us at the moment

Comment: @Jeremy Miller yes it says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''carads'' at line 1"

Comment: You got your answer.

Comment: `bpescorts` does not show up your query above (in addition to the answer)

Comment: Im a little slow here,but what does it mean by "line 1"

Comment: typo @JeremyMiller multitasking lol

Comment: Then it looks like accepting @Mureinik is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified some of your code. You did not select any database. Also there exist syntax error in sql string. Try this

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, 'db_name');
if (mysqli_connect_error()){
    die(mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    echo "<font  color='#00FF00'>CONNECTED TO DATABASE SUCCESSFULLY</font><br>";
}

foreach ($result as $wtf)
{
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn,"INSERT INTO carads (adlink) VALUES ('$wtf')");
    if(!$result){
        die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    echo "<font color='#FFFFFF'>INSERTING LINK INTO DATABASE: $wtf</font><br>";
}
$sql = "SELECT adlink FROM carads"; //Removed single quotes from here
$sqlresult = mysqli_query($conn,$sql );
if(!$sqlresult){
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    die("<font size='20' color='#FF0000'>idk man, there was an error and the dataset didnt get in there</font><br>") ;
}
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($sqlresult);
print_r ("<font size='18' color='#00FF00'>Car ads Database has %d ADLINKS from current city.\n</font><br>",$rowcount);
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Thanks alot man! You guys are the best here. What did people do before Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes (`'`) are used to denote character literals. In your select statement your trying to refer to object (column and table) names, so you should not be using them:

```
$sql="SELECT adlink FROM carads"; // Note the lack of quotes
$sqlresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! When I changed the code it gave me a new error. Database not selected. And now ever though it throws the same error when I manually check the database the records are in there. Even though Please Wait 's answer was the "final" correct one, I got to that answer from making the change you suggested. Thanks! @Mureinik

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quotes for columns and tables or use grave accent (`) instead.
I advise each time you are not sure about SQL queries try to do same operation in [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) and read the query it used to do that.

Comment: Thank you I will be sure to do that in the future @Moein Nourmohammadi